# SW1: 6e SW2:00 error on selecting card

Tags: javacard

I am trying to implement my first example of a Javacard applet, and on selecting the card by running the CREF simulator, I am getting the error `sw1: 6e sw2:00`

The tools that I am using are:

- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/2/eclipse-java-oxygen-2-win32-x86_64.zip)
- JDK 7
- [JCDK 2.2.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html#java_card_kit-2.2.2-oth-JPR)
- [Eclipse JCDE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-jcde/files/latest/download?source=files)

This is the definition of my applet:

```
public class Card extends Applet {
    /******************** Constants ************************/
    public static final byte CLA_CARDAPPLET = (byte) 0xB0;
    public static final byte INS_INCREMENT_COUNTER = 0x00;
    public static final byte INS_DECREMENT_COUNTER = 0x01;
    public static final byte INS_CHECK_COUNTER = 0x02;
    public static final byte INS_INITIALIZE_COUNTER = 0x03;

    /*********************** Variables ***************************/
    private byte counter;

    /************ Constructor **************/
    private Card() {
        counter = 0;
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength) throws ISOException {
        new Card().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] != CLA_CARDAPPLET) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }

        switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {
        case INS_INCREMENT_COUNTER:
            counter++;
            break;
        case INS_DECREMENT_COUNTER:
            counter--;
            break;
        case INS_CHECK_COUNTER:
            buffer[0] = counter;
            apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) 1);
            break;
        case INS_INITIALIZE_COUNTER:
            apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
            counter = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA];
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

To simulate the javacard, I am following these steps:

1. Execute `cref -o card.eeprom`
2. Upload the applet: `myPackage> Java Card Tools > Deploy`
3. Execute `cref -i card.eeprom -o card.eeprom`
4. Initialize the card by running `create-Card.script`
5. Execute `cref -i card.eeprom -o card.eeprom`
6. Select the card by running `select-Card.script`

The auto-generated content of the script `select-Card.script` is:

```
powerup;
// select Card applet
0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0xb 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x00 0x01 0x7F;
powerdown;
```

Where `0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x00 0x01` is the AID of the `Card` applet

The selection returns `sw1: 6e sw2:00`, and according to [scard.org](http://www.scard.org/software/info.html), the code `6e, 00` means that the class does not exist or is not supported, but which class? and how to make it recognizable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting `0x6E00` because of below mentioned line..

```
if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] != CLA_CARDAPPLET) {
       ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
   }
```

When you select applet it apdu reaches to your applet and it checks the class byte which is `0x00` in case of select applet command.

add below mentioned line on top of `process(APDU apdu)` method..

```
if (selectingApplet()) {
      return;
}
```

This line will just return `0x9000` as SW when you send select applet command.

Comment: It works fine, thanks! Can you still explain to me something please: Before posting the question, I commented the code that you mentioned `if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] != CLA_CARDAPPLET) ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);` but it didn't help to get rid of the problem

Comment: selectingApplet() method checks if Select applet APDU arrives to the applet and so in Applet selection we checked if it is applet selection command and returned from there.

Comment: For your own knowledge, you can throw exception instead of return or try to make check on INS byte and return if it is select applet.

Comment: if you comment out this line 'if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] != CLA_CARDAPPLET) ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);' Code should work fine, it will continue further and check INS byte and there is nothing written on default case so ideally it should return 0x9000